# Firefox CORS Cross Domain Resource Sharing Pre-Flight Debugging

Tags: ajax, firefox, cross-domain, cors, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to get Firefox to allow me to make an XmlHttpRequest for data from an application port.

I can see that the initial send triggers an OPTIONS message, and I have trapped this using NetMon, and I can see the HTTP fields...

```
OPTIONS /any.htm HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysite.co.uk:10090
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Origin: http://www.mysite.co.uk
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache  
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I respond to this with an OK to tell FireFox to get a move on and send me the data in the XHR request...

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,-GET,-OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 172800000
Server: Kawasu-OrderSub
Date: Wed, 23 Jan 2013 15:00:50 GMT
```

But the POST is never sent, which I assume means that FireFox is not happy with the 200 OK response.  The POST sends data with a Content-Type of "application/json"

I've got FireBug and the Net tab has the XHR button, but this will only show the XHR after the pre-flight check has been passed.

Main Question: How can I see (and debug) what FireFox does not like about the server response?

Much obliged for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type` response header. This is because the request has the `Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type` header, and this value needs to be included in the response.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks very much for the response, more feedback when I've rebuilt my server side code with the tweak...

Comment: No Joy.  Tomorrow will try limiting the request to be 'simple' in CORS terms (ie remove specified content-type) so that the pre-flight check is not triggered.  Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Removed Content-Type as an option, and that worked - Firefox no longer pre-flights the request, and I am back in the ball game.  Thanks for your help Monsur.

Comment: EXTRA: If anyone does know how to debug Firefox to see why the OPTIONS response fails to satisfy the browser and allow the POST, please add it here.  Much obliged!

Comment: I'm surprised Firebug doesn't display preflight info. It is displayed in Chrome's network inspector. You didn't mention if this works in Chrome or not, but it may be useful to debug in Chrome. I would recommend a HTTP inspector such as WireShark, Fiddler or Charles Proxy to view the actually HTTP requests/responses going over the wire.

Comment: Chrome will probably be next.  Firefox is now behaving at least, because the request is 'simple' if I don't specify the content-type.  For sniffing I'm using NetMon, only because it's the devil I know - it will also show TCP and HTTP conversations.  Much obliged for the help.

Comment: OK, Firefox works if I can avoid the pre-flight message being sent.  Chrome sends the preflight OPTIONS message anyway, even for the simplest of XHR's.  Then, I can see my server returning a message, but Chrome IGNORES the returned message and the state of the request stays pending.  I have NetMon'ed both ends of the TCP conversation and I can see the message arrive, but Chrome does not react.  How can I see what Chrome does not like about the response?

Comment: Is there a public test page you can set up to reproduce this behavior? I've never seen a case where one browser sends a preflight and the other does not.

Comment: I'll have to set up the scenario at the weekend, test it myself to make sure I'm not going nuts and making any stupid errors, then send you the details.  Reading around, this might be something to do with my site being Self Certificated SSL rather than Verisign, but as you get no diagnostics from the browser, it's guesswork.  Thanks for the offer of assistance though, really appreciate it.

Comment: OK, Got my test pages up.  If you go to www.kawasu.co.uk, the default.aspx home page has two links at the bottom.  

First time you go there, you have to set up a new user ID.  This is required because the system is an exchange, and requires a userID to differentiate your orders from other users'.  No info is required from the user other than simple log-on info, and you can use false details if you like, this is a demo site only.  The site is self-certificated.

Comment: Either of the links at the base of the first page take you to dynamic pages that attempt XHR requests via CORS.  

With Firefox, there is no pre-flight message, all is well.

In Chrome, I get a pre-flight OPTIONS request, which I believe I respond to correctly, but no POST arrives after my response to OPTIONS.

If I run Chrome with the command line option "--disable-web-security", Chrome does not pre-flight the message, 
so this is possibly Chrome going beyond the remit of standard CORS and applying additional security.

Comment: OK, I have the answer!  Chrome does not want you to modify the Connection or Origin request headers.  I have put a condition to detect Chrome as the browser, and I only set these headers if not Chrome, and by jingo, it works.  CORS for all.